# How can I structure an array like this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a specific structure:

[image: Where content has three arrays]

But I have no idea about how to make the function. I was trying with this:

```
const estructuringAccount = (account) => {
    return account.subaccounts.map(subaccount => {
        const arraysSubaccount = subaccount.summaries.map(content => {
            return {
                [content.type]: [
                    { month: "january", total: content.january },
                    { month: "february", total: content.february },
                    { month: "march", total: content.march },
                    { month: "april", total: content.april },
                    { month: "may", total: content.may },
                    { month: "june", total: content.june },
                    { month: "july", total: content.july },
                    { month: "august", total: content.august },
                    { month: "september", total: content.september },
                    { month: "october", total: content.october },
                    { month: "november", total: content.november },
                    { month: "december", total: content.december }
                ]
            }
        })
        return {
            key: subaccount.id,
            name: subaccount.name,
            content: [{
                year: subaccount.summaries[0].year,
                summary: subaccount.summaries[0].summary,
                ...arraysSubaccount
            }]
        }
    })
}
```

And the result is a bit different:

[image: it's from the api]

Is there any other way?

Comment: It's not clear what is the initial data and what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Can you post here the complete array ?

Comment: Where are `mtd`, `budget`, and `py` coming from?

Comment: It's a simple model. I need to structure like this in react to receive the original data. Each one (mtd, budget and py) has the same data, take them such as empty array.